Filtering logic with Elasticsearch (.net core/react)
I'm currently working with an Elasticsearch setup that houses around 100,000 records. In this setup, we utilize a React front end and a .NET Core back-end to dynamically filter data based on user inputs across approximately 20 fields. The user-inputted values dictate the filters, and these filters are applied in conjunction, using the "AND" operator (filter1 AND filter2 AND filter3), to retrieve matching data from Elasticsearch.
However, I am encountering a challenge. Each time a user adds a new filter, I need to send this updated filter set back to the .NET Core API, execute the query in Elasticsearch using the Nest library, and then return the results to the React front-end. This process, given the extensive filtering criteria and the need for continuous updating, raises a concern regarding server load and efficiency.
Given the complexity, including the fact that caching isn't feasible due to the variability and type of the filtering fields (double variables with thousands of permutations), I'm looking for any advice on optimizing this setup. Is there a more efficient logic or method to handle such dynamic and heavy filtering without overloading the server?
Thank you in advance for your help.

For now, I send all the filters instantly, filter them on elasticsearch and return the data.

const onFilterChanged = useCallback(() => {
  const api = gridApi;
  const filters = api.getFilterModel();
  const newFilterText = {};

  Object.keys(filters).forEach((key) => {
    newFilterText[key] = filters[key].filter;
  });

  apiCallDataFilter(newFilterText);
}, [gridApi, selectedRow]);


const apiCallDataFilter = async (filterText) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://localhost:1111/api/filter/FilterMatch",
      filterText
    );
    setRowData(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error filtering data:", error);
  }
};

Here, for filtering, I take the name and value of the filtering field as key value and send it to the API to filter in elastic search.
